# Can't Login after Logout in Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel project whose version is 6.4. Trying to build a simple authentication process. So went through the latest documentation as Laravel now considers authentication as a different package. What I face as a problem is that whenever I register it takes me to the home page which is obvious. But after logging out I can't log in to the system even if my credentials are correct. Any solution for that? Below is a list of commands I fired to do authentication scaffolding.

```
composer require laravel/ui

php artisan ui vue --auth

npm install && npm run dev // for views
```

My default auth `guard` is web which uses `session` driver.

I tried uncommenting the `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class` in the kernel, but still can't log in.

Answer (score 0):

Check the username field in the login form and database, this name should be the same as the value of the `username()` function in the file

```
Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php
```

Comment: it's matching with the name in my DB, but still can't log in

Comment: @MehediHassan Please also check the Login form input field name

Comment: This is worked for me since I changed the "email" to "phone", and I did "Composer Update" after.